# How to colorize a black-transparent PNG icon with ImageMagick

Tags: icons, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

**How do I a colorize a black PNG image that has a transparent background using ImageMagick?**

Use case:
You have several PNG images like this:
[image: Source image]

And I want to colorize them like this:
[image: Wished result]

I want to use ImageMagick's `convert` command, allowing for scripting to process hundreds of icons at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of the following commands:

```
$ convert input.png +level-colors "red", output.png
$ convert input.png +level-colors "rgb(255,0,0)", output.png
$ convert input.png +level-colors "#ff0000", output.png
```

Note that the `,` character is important here. On the left side of the `,` character we tell `convert` which color should replace **black** and on right side what color should replace **white**. Therefore nothing should be given after the `,` character.

[Source](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#level-colors)

Comment: How can I edit these commands so that they preserve alpha-transparency?

Comment: I can make it in two parts, first applying yours and then `convert output.png -transparent white result.png`. But can this be achieved in one command?

Comment: It seems to me that my command preserved transparency, but do you mean that it does not work with say, 50% transparency? (most pixels in my icons have 100% or 0% transparency so I could have missed that)

Comment: I found that 100% transparent icons are preserved. Thanks for this excellent tip! Super useful to quickly create variations of icons I've previously purchased licenses for

Answer (score 5):

> ... how do I colorize black & transparent PNG images [...] to colorize them like this [...] using ImageMagick

The `-fill <COLOR>` option works fantastic for this purpose.  You can replace `"#1bbfc9"` with a human-readable name (e.g. "red") or an HTML color code.

```
convert target-black.png -fill "#1bbfc9" -colorize 100 target-blue.png
```

> ... allowing to script and process hundreds of icons at a time

Using the `find` command, you can recurse hundreds.
**Warning:** This will replace the originals.

```
find path/to/files  -iname '*.png' -exec convert "{}" -fill "#1bbfc9" -colorize 100 "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

With ImageMagick, you can process a whole folder of images at one time with mogrify rather than convert if you want all the same color. Create a new output directory to hold the colorized files. Then cd to the folder holding your images.

```
cd path_to/image_folder
mogrify -format png -path path_to/new_folder -fill "cyan" -colorize 100 *.png
```

Where replace `path_to` with your actual path.

You may use color names, hex colors or rgb(...) colors in the fill command, but enclose them in quotes on Linux/Mac OSX.  Quotes are not needed for Windows, but should not cause any issues if double quotes.

See [mogrify](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify)